# BTCore or BlueZ?

Tags: bluetooth, c++

According to resources - bluetooth is now part of the Linux kernel.
Fine. It  makes bluetooth users life easy.

Not so for C++ programmer.

There seem to be TWO "stacks" - "BlueZ" and "BTCore".

Both of these "stacks"  are peculiarly void of actual source code documentation.

Is it too much to expect normal , C/C++ style - what does a function do, what are the parameters passed  what is the return value of the function etc.?

The question is:

**which one these stacks is most likely to be part of Linux in future?**

Or is "dbus" the way to develop in C++?

Answer (score 1):

## What the future holds

What the future holds is a difficult question in the computer world. Take for example:

- [Mark Shuttleworth stating in 2010 that Wayland will replace xorg in Ubuntu](https://lwn.net/Articles/415589/).

Finally in 2017 Ubuntu tried Wayland as a default. It didn't succeed so Xorg became the default again in 18.04.

---

As far as Bluetooth goes [this webpage](https://wiki.rdkcentral.com/display/RDK/bluetooth_mgr) sums up the current environment and predicts `BSA` ***could*** replace `Bluez` in the future:

### bluetooth_mgr

Bluetooth Provides an interface to port any Bluetooth application on RDK. Bluetooth Manager (An RDK component) interfaces with BlueZ through the D-Bus API, so there is no direct linking of the BlueZ library with Bluetooth Manager.

In RDK, Bluetooth is comprised of a Core module (BTCore) and a Manager module (BTMgr).  The BTCore module controls basic Bluetooth functionality such as scanning, pairing, and connecting.  The BTMgr module uses the services of the BTCore module for performing audio streaming.  RDK has two utilities for testing.  A btrCoreTest utility tests the BTCore functions.  A btrMgrStreamOutCoreTest utility tests BTMgr functions.  Both utilities share some common functionality.  For example, it is possible to perform a device scan using either utility.

#### Bluez

In its current implementation, the RDK Bluetooth uses the Bluez stack.  It is possible that another stack (e.g. Broadcom’s BSA) could be used in the future.

#### DBUS

The Bluez stack uses DBus to facilitate communication between the user application and the kernel level Bluetooth functions.

#### gStreamer

BTMgr utilizes gStreamer to process incoming Bluetooth data

---

I don't usually answer questions I've voted to close as too broad. In this case someone (who I initially mistook to be you) took the time to change your question based on my comments. As such I felt I should take the time to at least attempt an answer.